# How to print this pattern?

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to print the following pattern

```
0  0  0  0  0<br>
0  #  #  #  0<br>
0  #  0  #  0<br>
0  #  #  #  0<br>
0  0  0  0  0
```

The code which I have written prints this

```
0  0  0  0  0<br>
0  #  #  #  0<br>
0  #  #  #  0<br>
0  #  #  #  0<br>
0  0  0  0  0<br>
```

and the code is

```
public class PrintPattern {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int [][] arr = new int[5][5];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){

            if(i>0 && i<4 && j!=0 && j!=4){
                arr[i][j]=1;
            }

        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(arr[i][j]==1){
                System.out.print(" "+"#"+" ");
            }
            else
                System.out.print(" "+arr[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }



}
}
```

Also I need to generalize it for any `n` x `n` matrix where `n = {2k+1,k>0}`.

Comment: What is the pattern? A ring in the middle? Alternating rings?

Comment: You should make it clear for higher order conditions. Is there only a single '0' in the center or should it be 0#0# sequence in both directions?

Comment: outer ring of zeros then an inner ring of # and so on

Comment: Is number of rows fixed at 5? What exactly do you mean by `so on`?

Comment: The first version of your question was better--it showed what you've tried and what didn't work.  Show us some code we can critique, don't just ask for a solution.

Comment: the number of rows is not fixed at 5 , it is an example . the number of rows could be any odd integer. I want to print an outer ring with zeros then an inner ring with # then again a ring with zeros and so on depending upon the value of the number of rows

Comment: +1 for putting the effort for trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try to figure out the constant.

here:

```
int center = n / 2;
for each node(x, y):
    int dist = max(abs(x - center), abs(y - center));
    if (dist % 2 == 0) ch = '0';
    else ch = '#'
```

Comment: yes, this algo does solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: this is the method I implemented in java `public static void print(int n){
  int center = n/2;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
    int dist = max(Math.abs(i-center),Math.abs(j-center));
    if((dist & 1)==0){
     arr[i][j]=0;
    }
    else{
     arr[i][j]=1;
    }
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: could you please explain this `int dist = max(abs(x - center), abs(y - center))` ?

Comment: @n1234 that's what i call `constant`, you may take it as the distance to the center point, whose parity implies the kind of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You try the code below

```
public class PrintPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

            for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {

                if(i==0 || i==4) {

                    System.out.print("0 ");
                    continue;
                }
                else if(j>0 && j<4 && (i != 2 || j != 2)) {

                   System.out.print("# ");
                   continue;
               }
               else
               System.out.print("0 ");
          }

          System.out.print("\n");
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: 0 0 0 0 0<br>
0 # 0 # 0<br> 
0 0 0 0 0<br> 
0 # 0 # 0<br>  
0 0 0 0 0    is the output from your code but changing `else if(j>0 && j<4 && i != 2 && j != 2)` to `else if(j>0 && j<4 && (i != 2 || j != 2))` does the trick

Comment: yes it works with some modification, see the comment above. Please edit your code.